# Which cryptocurrency has the smallest block time?

Tags: block, alternatives, altcoin-development, block-interval

What is the lowest block time of any cryptocurrency? I don't mean the time of an individual block, but the target time per block.

What is the shortest reasonable block interval?

Comment: Lower block time is not a feature, it's an outright bug and security risk. There are very good reasons for the 10 minutes and any alt coin that tries to sell anything less as a feature is scamming people. Shorter blocktimes waste hashing power and favor centralization.

Comment: Unless centralization is what you want/need

Comment: if that's their evil secret plan, then yes. Honest centralization can do away with the entire blockchain and be more efficient altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a coin called [Flashcoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=222450.0) that tried to do 6-second block times. I don't think that's being actively mined anymore as another [Flashcoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=635403) appeared a year later (60-second block times).

[Ethereum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethereum) is planning a 12-second block time. Vitalik makes an argument for why that's probably the minimum for now [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/07/11/toward-a-12-second-block-time/). Of course, ethereum hasn't been released yet, but [Fastcoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=218852.0) with its 12-second block time is probably considered the lowest block generation time currently.

Answer (score 3):

EOS has blocks that are published every ~500ms, so around two blocks per second. That's a contender for the top spot for sure